# Web server unable to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

I have a site working under IIS7 and it was working fine. Someone restarted the server and after that it stopped working. After searching about the issue I found it is unable to connect to SQL Server and here is the error:

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

I didn't do any changes and the site was working fine but this problem happened only after restart, I checked SQL server remote access and TCP protocol and they were enabled. How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Check if you are able to connect to SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio. If not one of your SQL Server service might be down.

Comment: @achinth I'm able to connect through SQL management studio

Answer (score 1):

- Check connection strings (shouldn't
  be this if you didn't touch it)
- Check that the SQL services are up and running
- Try connect to the SQL server instance via Management Studio or another client

EDIT:

The error may be due to a network issue relating to the reboot. Try these out

Part 1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/22/483684.aspx

Part 2: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/29/486861.aspx

Comment: other webservers are able to connect with it fine except for this one same thing with connection string.